# Minimize the longest King chain on a 6x6 ternary grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, chess, optimization, graph-theory

This puzzle is an extension of this one: [Minimize the longest King chain on a 5x5 binary board](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107347/minimize-the-longest-king-chain-on-a-5x5-binary-board)

Given a grid filled with numbers, we define a **King chain** to be a path on the grid such that:

1. The path can be traversed with chess King's moves (moving to one of 8 adjacent cells at a time),
2. The numbers on the path are all equal, and
3. The path does not visit any cell more than once.

The **length** of a King chain is the number of cells visited by the King.

Can you find a **6x6** grid filled with **zeros, ones and twos**, such that every pair of cells with the same number are connected via some King chain, and the longest King chain has **length 7**?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there is a 'nice' solution to this? If not, this seems more like a computer programming challenge than a puzzle.

Comment: I have found the optimal solution to this puzzle and the solution is 'nice'.

Comment: One could argue that the original puzzle on 5x5 did not have a 'nice' solution either.

Comment: Yes, but people's tolerance of questions that skirt the lines of "puzzle" versus "programming problem" generally decreases as more are posted. Now that we know the previous one had no 'nice' solution, I think it is much closer to "programming problem" than "puzzle". It was unclear at the start, though. This question (and the similar one you asked at about the same time) seem to just be making it harder, meaning it is even *less* likely that it has a 'nice' solution.

Comment: Ok let's see what the community thinks. If some people enjoy solving this problem (I know I do!) then the puzzle should remain open for those people.

Comment: @Deusovi You probably just missed it: OP says explicitly, they have an optimal solution and it is nice. At which point continuing to go on about a nice solution being unlikely invites misunderstanding. Shouldn't we all default to believing what people are saying? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Albert.Lang I was responding to this conversation and [the other](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107490/minimize-the-longest-king-chain-on-a-7x7-binary-grid?noredirect=1&lq=1) at the same time; in the other, they said they had an arrangement that *might* be optimal but no proof. Based on the other question (as well as previous conversations with them about optimization questions), I had assumed that they meant "many options were tried and this seemed to be the best, but there isn't necessarily an airtight proof". I was also trying to talk about [...]

Comment: [...] both questions rather than just this one, but I realize that probably wasn't clear from this comment.

Comment: @Deusovi I see. As I said I do not suggest any malice. All I'm saying is that it can be misread. Btw. I for one quite enjoy those "open-ended" optimisation/construction problems for the one-up-man-ship they often generate.

Comment: I have modified the puzzle so it is now asking for a specific length, which I know is possible to achieve. This should make it more of a puzzle.

Comment: Looks much better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: All solutions up to mirror symmetry, rotation, colour permutation found by brute force:

> [image]

End of EDIT.

One possibility (I write X,O,+ for 0,1,2):

> ```
>     + X + O X X
>     O + X O X O
>     + O X X O O
>     + X O O X X
>     + O + X O X
>     O + O X O O
> ```

A bit on how this was found:

> To cover as much as possible with one path as short as possible we want it to branch:

> Here is one promising pattern (left core pattern, right with example set of subbranches)
>
> ```
>     . . . . . .     . . . O . O
>     O . . . . O     O . . O . O
>     . O . . O .     . O . . O .
>     . . O O . .     . . O O . .
>     . O . . O .     . O . . O O
>     O . . . . O     O . O . . O
> ```

> We can neatly fit two of those:
>
> ```
>     X . . . . X
>     O X . . X O
>     . O X X O .
>     . X O O X .
>     X O . . O X
>     O . . . . O
> ```

> Now the centre is blocked we can reasonably expect the third colour to cover maybe half the grid but not all. The other half we need to cover using only X and O. This can be done symmetrically:
>
> ```
>     X . X O X X
>     O X . O X O
>     . O X X O O
>     . X O O X X
>     X O . X O X
>     O . O X O O
> ```

> It remains to connect the leftover area. This can be done by small adjustments that break symmetry
>
> ```
>     . X . O X X
>     O . X O X O
>     . O X X O O
>     . X O O X X
>     . O . X O X
>     O . O X O O
> ```

Comment: Beautiful work. Well done!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I've added a picture of what I believe are all 315 distinct solutions.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like this can be improved but the best I've been able to do so far is

> 8

As follows

> ```
> 2 2 2 2 2 2
> 2 0 1 0 1 2
> 1 0 1 0 1 0
> 1 0 1 0 1 0
> 0 1 0 1 0 1
> 0 1 0 1 0 1
> ```

Comment: Great start. See my modification to the puzzle. I am now asking for length 7, which I know is possible.